Poisson distribution and expectation
Let $X$ be Poisson distributed with parameter $\mu>0$. It is well known, that for the expectation holds $E(X)=\sum\limits_{l=0}^{\infty}l\cdot \frac{\mu^l}{l!}e^{-\mu}=\mu$. However, does anyone know how to prove the following:
$$\mu\cdot \sum\limits_{l=0}^{x-1}\frac{\mu^l}{l!}e^{-\mu}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{x}k\cdot \frac{\mu^k}{k!}e^{-\mu}.$$
Probably the previous statement is valid for any discrete distribution with probability mass function $f$:
$$\mu\cdot \sum\limits_{l=0}^{x-1}f(l)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{x}k\cdot f(k).$$
Thanks in advance!

$\mu\cdot \sum\limits_{l=0}^{x-1}f(l)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{x}k\cdot f(k)$ is not correct for general $x$ in non-Poisson distributions on (a subset of) the non-negative integers, though it is trivially correct when $x$ is above the maximum of the the support as you get $E[X]\times 1 = E[X]$.

It's a change of indices. Since the first term is $0$, the right-hand side equals
$$\sum_{k=1}^xk\cdot\frac{\mu^k}{k!}=\sum_{k=1}^x\frac{\mu^k}{(k-1)!}=\mu\sum_{k=1}^x\frac{\mu^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}$$
And setting $l=k-1$ you get the desired identity
